# Sturm-Liouville: trick for the sign of $\lambda$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, sturm-liouville

I have a quick question about the Sturm-Liouville problems.

Does someone has a trick to know wether we have to define $\omega := -\lambda^2$ or $\omega = \lambda^2$, i.e. if $\lambda$ must be positive or negative? I know it can be seen with converting the differential equation into the form $(py')' + qy = r\lambda y$ but it takes time and I need to be fast.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: That can depend on the boundary conditions and the range of $q$. You might compare this situation to the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem.

Comment: There are cases where $\omega$ can be positive for some solutions and negative for others. You can't assume that $\omega$ is going to be strictly positive or strictly negataive.